# Javascript Rectangle inside webcam stream

Tags: javascript, typescript, qr-code, webcam, getusermedia

> **I am very sorry for the UI of the question, I do not know why images**
> **are so huge. Please accept my apologies.**

I am doing a QrCodeScanner with browser's getUserMedia and up to now have got this.

Please do not pay attention to buttons [SCAN QR, STOP QR], the camera is between them.

[image: While starting the stream and scanning for QRcode]

**What I want is something like this**
[image: Box showing a specific area inside the camera]

Does anyone know what the way of doing it is?

Comment: SImple css overlay will work like a charm

Comment: @bZezzz What if it covers exactly the qr-code however it does not recognize it? I mean do I not have to take it somewhere from the stream?

Comment: The stream is not affected by css overlay. Post your code here, I'll make it work and then explain it.